# Convergence of the Fourier integral at a point

Tags: fourier-analysis, piecewise-continuity

I'm studying this theorem on Zorich II:

*(Convergence of the Fourier integral at a point) Let $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{C}$ be an
absolutely integrable function that is piecewise continuous on each finite closed
interval of the real axis $\mathbb{R} $.
If the function f satisfies the Dini conditions at a point $x ∈ R$, then its Fourier
integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{f}(\xi) e^{i\xi x}\mathrm{d}\xi$$
converges at that point to the value
$(f (x^−) + f (x^+))/2$, equal to half the sum of the left and right-hand limits of the
function at that point.*

I can't understand why the hypothesis of the piecewise continuity is necessary. It is used only to say that, for every finite $A>0$ and $B>0$:

$$\int_{-A}^A \left(\int_{-B}^B f(t)e^{-i\xi t} \mathrm{d}t\right) e^{i\xi x \mathrm{d}\xi}=\int_{-B}^B f(t) \left(\int_{-A}^A e^{i\xi (x-t)} \mathrm{d}\xi\right)\mathrm{d}t$$

Can't I say the same thing using Fubini theorem?

Comment: Is it for the Riemann or Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Riemann integral

Comment: Yeah, so the hypothesis is here to insure Riemann integrability I think.

Comment: Why not Riemann integrability? Continuity is an extra hypothesis, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right, Riemann integrability only implies continuity almost everywhere ... but are you sure it is not used somewhere else in the proof? In particular, I am not sure one can define the left and right limits for general Riemann integrable functions?